# The Google Analytics frequency and recency reports shows more sessions than I have for a day

Tags: google-analytics, visitors, session

In Audience --> Behavior --> Frequency & Recency --> Days Since Last Session

I for the Value 0 I have 3000 sessions. **If** I understand this correctly, it means that 3000 sessions happened today. Yet, I do not have 3000 sessions today.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean you had 3,000 sessions today. It means that for the time range you are looking at, 3,000 users visited on one day, and had no returning sessions

The next row for 1 means that whatever the number is there is the number who returned to make another visit after 1 day

the next row for the number who returned to make another visit after 2 days etc etc